# Doctrine2: undefined index

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

When I try to execute this DQL query:

```
SELECT r, s FROM Rule r
JOIN r.splash_page s
WHERE r.active = 1
```

What I'm trying to do is just join two Entities and I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 110
Notice: Undefined index: rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 428
Notice: Undefined index: rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 428
Notice: Undefined index: rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 428
Notice: Undefined index: rules in C:\xampp\htdocs\excap\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 428
```

These are part of my Entity files where I declare the relation between them:

```
// Rule.php 
/**
 *
 * @var type 
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="SplashPage", inversedBy="rules")
 */
protected $splash_page;
```

---

```
// SplashPage.php
/**
 *
 * @var type
 * OneToMany(targetEntity="Rule", mappedBy="splash_page") 
 */
protected $rules = null;
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your `$rules` docblock: you have forgotten the `@` sign before OneToMany

The docblock should be:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Rule", mappedBy="splash_page") 
 */
protected $rules = null;
```

instead of

```
/**
 * OneToMany(targetEntity="Rule", mappedBy="splash_page") 
 */
protected $rules = null;
```